# Alternative to % margin for spacing between main body and footer?

Tags: css

I created a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page, but the problem is that it lines up immediately after my last image so there is no spacing between them. I want to put space between the last image and the footer, so I thought creating a % based margin would be a good solution. However I had to use a `margin-bottom:180%` which seems sloppy to me and would present problems upon resizing the window. My code essentially is (removed extra images to prevent clutter):

```
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<section class='gallery-set'>
<div class='wrap'>
    <img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'/>
  <div class='ontop'><p class='example-text'>Overlay Test text </p></div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

So my goal here is to create a space between the footer and the rest of the content.

Comment: A jsFiddle of the example would be very helpful here if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind static, try use `px`. If you want to be a bit more dynamic, try use `em`

```
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-bottom: 5em;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

```
 1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font.
 E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt. The 'em' is a
 very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader uses
```

Comment: wouldn't em present the same problems as %? Or will the value of em change as the browser window is resized?